# SSL Protocol error in jmeter recording

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, recording, jmeter

I am trying to record Android app scenario through Jmeter.

Have enabled the proxy and applied the certificates, but in-between the recording , i am seeing SSL error issue where i am unable to proceed further.

Could be something we need to check with the certificate may be. Expecting some of your help ,to resolve the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On recent Android versions there was an enforcement of security when it comes to handling certificates so you need to amend your application [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) in order to be able to record its network activity via JMeter:

1. In your [android application manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro) file add the following setting in the `<application>` tag:

   ```
   android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
   ```
2. Create the `/src/{packageMain}/res` folder if it doesn't exist and add `network_security_config.xml` file with the following content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <network-security-config>
       <debug-overrides>
           <trust-anchors>
               <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
               <certificates src="user"/>
           </trust-anchors>
       </debug-overrides>
   </network-security-config>
   ```
3. [Build debug APK](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline) like

   ```
   gradlew assembleDebug
   ```
4. That's it, now you should be able to install JMeter's `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` onto the device and JMeter will capture your application traffic.

More information: [Recording Using Android Devices](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices-Recording-Using-Android-Devices)